# "func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', and 'd'"

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a Gaussian with on the following dataset (could not paste it all but hopefully that is enough rows)

```
2.738237424 0.1956847
2.742886384 0.1956847
2.747535344 0.1956847
2.752184304 0.1956847
2.756833264 0.1776788
2.761482224 0.1956847
2.766131184 0.1956847
2.770780144 0.1776788
2.775429104 0.1776788
2.780078064 0.1956847
2.784727024 0.1956847
2.789375984 0.1956847
2.794024944 0.1776788
2.798673904 0.1776788
2.803322862 0.1956847
```

Here is my code:
    x = data[590:880,0]
    y = data[590:880,1]

```
error = np.repeat(0.001, (880 - 590))

# Model object
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-b)**2/c**2) + d

quad_model = odr.Model(func)

 # Create a RealData object
dataset = odr.RealData(x, y, sx=error)

# Set up ODR with the model and data.
odr = odr.ODR(dataset, quad_model, beta0=[-0.6, 3.7, -0.4, 0.2])
```

I get the message "func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', and 'd'"
Do you know what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: The never ending battle... please post the stack trace which highlights the line with the error. Python did the work... pay it forward!

Comment: Looks like the Model is calling your `func()` with only two arguments. Are you sure you have you have the signature of `func()` correct?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.odr.Model.html) for `odr.Model` states that `fcn` takes only two arguments.

You defined `func` with 5 required arguments, so Python is throwing an error because the model is internally trying to call a 5-argument function with only 2 arguments.

Comment: Note that you use beta0 as a list, try func(x, parameter_list) as well.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, I think this should be a comment on the question, not the answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct, my note is on implementing your correct answer.